# Apache rewrite rule not working (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ubuntu-16.04

I'm using the following `.htaccess` file on Ubuntu 16.04 with Apache 2.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

I'm using that configuration to allow [this PHP router](https://github.com/bramus/router/) to work on my website.

However, none of the defined routes appear to work correctly on my linux server (404), while they work fine on my local windows installation. This leads me to think that the htaccess isn't being interpreted properly.

What I've done:

- Restarted apache (multiple times).
- Enabled the rewrite mod with `sudo a2enmod rewrite`
- In the site's configuration `/etc/apache2/sites-available/website.com.conf`, added:

  ```
  <Directory "/var/www/website.com/public_html">
  AllowOverride All
  </Directory>
  ```

  under my virtual host

Comment: And the php script runs if you visit it directly?

Comment: @Walf yes it all works fine on the exact same setup on Windows

Comment: Have you tried disabling `mod_negotiation`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was accessing the defined routes directly via my browser. (so `website.com/api/v1/login/`) However, these routes only accepted POST requests, and therefore I was receiving the 404 error code.

Comment: Clbuttic mistake :) Glad you fixed it. Using a tool like [RESTer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/rester/) is best if you're testing APIs.